# VPS bandwidth usage

Tags: vps, network-monitoring

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 for my VPS. Recently I have noticed an extreme download on it, but I don't know what is the website/service that may cause that.

I have looked through but most solutions are about installing new tool that will not monitor the past behavior.

So is there any tool come with Ubuntu shows the bandwidth usage and in what it used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install any network-monitoring tool to start monitoring from this point forward, but for monitoring the past, you'll have to wait until time travel has been invented and then install a time-travel tool...  **;-)**

*Just a humorous way to tell you that what you're asking is impossible:* if Ubuntu wasn't set up for network monitoring in the past, it didn't monitor it, therefore you cannot get the data...